# Access my model using a daemon on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, daemon

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems' unless defined?(Gem)
require 'mongoid'
include Mongoid::Document

@classes = Availability.where(:availability_date.gt => Time.now.utc + 1.hours).to_a
puts @classes.count
```

But I always get:

classes_notification.rb:6:in `': uninitialized constant Availability (NameError)

Some help please, I need to make a daemon to send emails with the information on my availability model.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE CODE

---

```
my script is under app/script/user/remeber_classes.rb
```

how can I access the require File.dirname(**FILE**) + "/../../config/environment"

because I'm getting

> /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- ./../../config/environments
>   (LoadError)   from
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in`
>   require'     from remember_class.rb:5:in `'

Comment: Hi if you need it with rails app together, you may use background workers like delayed_job, sidekique, resque.
If you're making it like a separate application
you should
make a separate class
`class Availability
   include Mongoid::Document
   ... your fields ...
end`
require it. And then you should be able to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must include rails environment first
add `require "path_to_the_application/config/environment"` to your code

or

you can always access the database directly using mongo gem
see this

> https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your answer rejin. Could you showme how. Thanks

Comment: @jean try running with rails runner. ``rails runner app/script/user/remeber_classes.rb`` instead of ``ruby app/script/user/remeber_classes.rb``